# Figure in the wrong chapter in list figures

Tags: floats, lists, tufte

I am using the Tufte book for my book. When I create the List of Figures, one Marginfigure slips into the previous chapter group.

[image: List of figures with wrong ordering]

"Tiles in the pool" (marginfigure) is in the same chapter as "Drawing lines" (figure). Notice that also the numbering is wrong 9,11,10.

The page itself renders just fine:

[image: Placement of figures on page]

The LaTeX code for this page is also pretty straight forward. There are no compiling errors.

```
\chapter{Patterns}
\label{ch:patterns}

\section{Impossible Squares}
\label{se:impossible-squares}
\index{Impossible Squares}\index{Patterns!Impossible Squares}
Modern pools often have 10 lanes, each 2.5 meters wide. This gives the pool a square shape with a width of 25 meters which results in an area of $25\times25=625m^2$. When the pool uses square tiles then interesting patterns emerge. If we ignore the gaps between the tiles and a single tile is 25 cm then the pool will have $100^2=10,000$ tiles.

This grid of tiles is ideal for thinking about squares (see Figure \ref{fig:tiles}). The corners at which the tiles connect give us a grid of points (see Figure \ref{fig:impossible-squares01}). The rule for drawing is that you can only draw lines by connecting points. 

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{patterns/impossible-squares/impossible-squares-01.pdf}
\caption[Drawing lines][6pt]{Lines can be drawn onto the grid by connecting points.}
\label{fig:impossible-squares01}
\end{figure}

If we draw a square by moving one tile across and one tile down then we get a square with the surface of $1\times1=1$ tiles (see Figure \ref{fig:impossible-squares02},i). In our modern pool this would be $25^2=625$ square centimetres or 0.0625 $m^2$. We can also easily draw a $2\times2$ square with the surface of $4$ tiles (see Figure \ref{fig:impossible-squares02},ii) or a $3\times3$ square with a surface of $9$ tiles (see Figure \ref{fig:impossible-squares02}iii). Any square with the surface $a^2$ can be easily drawn where $a$ is the number of tiles for the side of the square. Drawing square numbers on a grid of squares is an obvious pattern. Let's call these types of squares ``regular squares'' and give it the letter $R$ as its symbol.
\begin{marginfigure}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{patterns/impossible-squares/tiles-bw.jpg}
\caption[Tiles in pool]{Square tiles in a swimming pool.}
\label{fig:tiles}
\end{marginfigure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be easier to answer your question if you completed your example of code to make it compilable.

Comment: The list of figures is created by the command ```\listoffigures``` The LaTeX code for page 15 is above. What else would be useful?

Comment: It also has the wrong figure number.  It takes 2 or 3 runs to have changes show up in the LOF.